# How can I set up a field / element on a form with a value that is hidden?

Tags: jquery

I have code like the following in an external script:

```
var contentID = $('#ContentID').val();
```

How can I set up on my form a hidden field with an ID of "#ContentID" and a value of for example 99? I just want the value to always be 99 on that form and the value will never change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have a form like this:

```
<form id="myform"></form>
```

you can do somethign like this:

```
var hidden = $('<input>').attr('id', 'ContentID').attr('type', 'hidden').val('99');
$('#myform').append(hidden);
```

Live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fXHqm/

Answer (score 2):

```
<input name="content" id="content" type="hidden" value="99">
```